# Error in installing the blackberry enterprise service 10 trial version

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am trying to install the BES 10(Blackberry enterprise service 10) in windows 7 os . I am stuck in SRP configuration. It Caught stuck in finalize initialization with the following error. Any idea to resolve them.

**<#01>[10000] (07/02 13:54:19.638):{0xDF8} CWebRequestWrapper::SubmitData: WinHttpQueryHeaders failing. Error code: 0. Status code: 405.

<#01>[10000] (07/02 13:54:19.638):{0xDF8} CRestApiWrapper::SetCertificateAttributes error sending data, result is [486003]

<#01>[10000] (07/02 13:54:19.638):{0xDF8} CDataContainer::DoApplyImpl: UbitexxCoreDataCon failed to apply. Result: 486023.

<#01>[10000] (07/02 13:54:19.638):{0xDF8} [CUbitexxCoreDataCon::Apply]: Failed to apply 'configuration.core.url.primary1' parameter.

<#02>[20000] (07/02 13:54:19.638):{0xDF8} CInstallStepSeq::PreApplyProcess: Errors encountered while applying Core Module. Core module may not be operational.**

Comment: Sorry couldnt add the screen shot as i have less reputation.

Comment: Just add link to the image, and someone else will put it in

Comment: I think you should ask this on BlackBerry Support Forums, people there know what's going on.

Comment: @Bojan Kogoj I will also give in blackberry support forum

Comment: @BojanKogoj How to add link to the image and someone else will put it , i dont understand the second comment of yourss

Comment: just put image on imgur and we'll put it in the post. just give link to it

Comment: I have changed the question as i solved the previous error. Now i am stuck in the following error. Help me to resolve them

Comment: @BojanKogoj can you with the question